# Specify Minimum Font Size in Safari 10.0, macOS Sierra

Tags: safari, font, macos

The Minimum Font Size option seems to be missing in Safari 10.0 / macOS Sierra.  It's been replaced by Page Zoom (prefs > advanced).  I'm specifically asking how to prevent Safari in Sierra from ever using a font size below a certain value.  I don't want to have to fix this on a site by site basis.

Let's say I want to set 11px as the minimum font size in Safari on macOS Sierra.  How do I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use

```
defaults write com.apple.Safari com.apple.Safari.ContentPageGroupIdentifier.WebKit2MinimumFontSize -int 14
```

… restart Safari, be happy again! (replace 14 with whatever suits you)

edit: as OP said, paste the line into terminal, sorry for omitting this initially!

Comment: WHOA!!!  Yes!!!  Thats FANTASTIC!  ...just in case it isn't clear to others who may stumble onto this page while searching for a solution, copy/paste that into Terminal.

Comment: Warning: only Sierra. On El Capitain it shows an error because the syntax is wrong for El Capitain.

So far I could find a corresponding setting for El Capitain...

Answer (score 0):

Since there's not currently a 'minimum font size' option in version 10 of Safari, I see two possible workaround options open to you:

1. Using a custom style sheet
2. Installing an extension

**Style sheet**

If you know how to create your own style sheet, then follow these steps:

1. Create a style sheet to set your font properties
2. Go to the Safari > Preferences menu
3. Select the Advanced tab
4. In the Style Sheet drop-down menu, select Other...
5. Navigate to your style sheet and select it
6. Exit the Safari preferences.

**Note:** If you want your style sheet to apply the font size to all elements, you can use an asterisk to imply that your code runs on all elements. For example:

```
* {
 font-size: your value;
 font-family: your font;
 font-weight: your value;
}
```

**Extension**

There are probably many extensions that will achieve what you want. Here are the steps for one that I'm aware of:

1. Go to: https://safari-extensions.apple.com/details/?id=com.sobolev.stylish-5555L95H45
2. Install the Stylish extension
3. Restart Safari
4. Take note that to the left of the address bar you should now see the Stylish S button
5. Go to: https://userstyles.org/styles/68263/global-font-size
6. Click on the Install with Stylish button
7. You've now installed this style

Now, if you need to customise this style, do the following:

1. click on the Stylish S button I referred to at Step 4 above.
2. Click on Manage
3. Under the Global Font Size option click on Edit
4. This displays the CSS code for this style. Edit it as you need.
5. Save your changes

**Note:** If you want your style sheet to apply the font size to all elements, you can use an asterisk to imply that your code runs on all elements. For example:

```
* {
 font-size: your value;
 font-family: your font;
 font-weight: your value;
}
```

**Feedback**

Anyone wanting Apple to return the 'minimum font size' option to Safari should send them feedback via the [Safari feedback](http://www.apple.com/feedback/safari.html) page.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The problem with those solutions is they both rely on CSS, and to the best of my knowledge is that there's no way to specify a minimum font size for any and or all elements...  or is there?

I'm already using a custom stylesheet for Safari, so if there's a way to force a minimum font size, please do tell!

Comment: I'm not 100% sure. You could try the Stylish extension and set it to apply globally to all sites and see what happens by default. If it doesn't work the way you want, you could try editing the CSS using an asterisk (which implies all elements). For example: `* { font-size: 100%; font-family: Arial; }` Of course, you would substitute the size and font for what you wanted. Let me know if this works and I'll edit my answer for the benefit of others.

Comment: My question is specific.  I'm asking how to set a minimum font size in Safari for macOS Sierra.  I appreciate the reply, but it doesn't answer my specific question.  If anything, it would make matters significantly worse by scaling all fonts.

Comment: I do appreciate your point and how specific your question is :) but many users are looking for an answer, not just users of Sierra (Safari 10 is also an update independent of macOS). I know my answer isn't the most ideal solution (hence me calling them 'workaround options') but I've posted it because it may be useful to others. For what it's worth, I've submitted feedback to Apple about this on the basis of accessibility (they have a soft spot for providing accessibility options). They need to bring this option back to Safari, but we must [tell them](http://www.apple.com/feedback/safari.html).

Comment: I asked a specific question.  I understand you're trying to help, but if your answers aren't answering the specific question that was asked, they're not helpful.  Generic answers about trying CSS, for example, are vague and not helpful.  I'd already thought of that and researched it - including here on stack exchange.  I came up empty, which is why I asked my question here.  I'm not trying to make fonts bigger.  I'm trying to find a way to set a minimum font size in Safari on macOS Sierra.

Answer (score -1):

Go to Finder then Applications click on Safari then go to view in the menu bar click and a drop down list appears click on, Show view options, and a drop down box appears Applications where you will see a text sizing box set to your preference and set as default.

Comment: That doesn't answer the question of how to set minimum font size.  There's a difference between resizing a font and setting a minimum font size.